# high-dimensional multivariate regression with R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, multivariate-analysis

think of the following data:

- *two* z-standardized *dependent* variables = *continuous* (here, both reflect a deviation of age but in different tissues)
- *many predictors* for a rather small data set, possibly multicollinearity (here, overall n ~ 300 and around 30 predictors)

Aim: **Predict** the value of the two dependent variables & **figure out what influences the outcome** on the dependent variables

My very first approach was to build groups from the 2 outcomes (e.g. high value on both dimensions, low value on both dimensions etc...) and run multinomial logistic regression. Problem: I've had to build somewhat arbitrary groups. All individuals rather lie together in one cloud.

My question is: What would be a good approach for analyzing this in R? So basically I want to predict where on these two dimensions an individual lies and I want to know what predictors are useful for that.

I found several potential techniques, e.g. multinomial relevance vector regression (I found no R package for that, especially as I need to learn it), multivariate regression (there I am missing the combination of the two dependent variables), pls regression (problem that I don't see which predictors are important), SEM (problem because of the many predictors)...

I'd be grateful for any recommendations on R packages or sites that could help me with this.

Comment: Could you explain how multinomial logistic regression--which is a procedure for modeling *discrete* outcomes--can be applied to, and might be meaningful for, a pair of *continuous* dependent variables?

Comment: Well as I wrote I used these two variables to build groups. Then I used multinomial logistic regression to predict the groups. Sure, this is not optimal why I now want to use something multivariate. However I thought this could be a first approach, because I had the chance to group extreme cases, and these are the ones I am most interested in.